# passing 'options' overrides to jquery function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery.mobile-1.0.1.

I'm trying to make the page reload when clicking on the current 'tab' in a ui-listview:

[image]

I've managed to track down the function and change the source code in jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js to fix this but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it *without modifying the jquery-mobile source*.

The function in question is:

```
$.mobile.loadPage = function( url, options ) {      
settings = $.extend( {}, $.mobile.loadPage.defaults, options ),
//rest omitted
```

I can see it is combining the default settings (`mobile.loadPage.defaults`) with user defined `options`

You need to pass reloadPage: true via options as the default is false.

If I follow the call stack upwards it logically (for the purposes of passing arguments) stops at

```
$.mobile.changePage( href, { transition: transition, reverse: reverse, role: role } );
```

so I passed in reloadPage:true in here but that would be modifying the source code of  jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js which I'm trying to avoid.

I'm new to js and jquery so unsure if there is some standard way to pass these options down as it appears thats the way it was designed, or perhaps it was designed this way for use by jquery.mobile internally and changing the source is the only way.

I'm wondering if there is some global way of setting arguments/options that would be available to this function; it seems strange the jquery mobile guys would seemingly code for `reloadPage` but not expose it for callees.

Comment: could be more specific about what you wanna do ? is your problem trying to override 'defaults' with 'options', and doesn't change? is this it ?

Comment: I want to pass `reloadPage: true` via options as the default is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way was to add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.mobile.loadPage.defaults.reloadPage = true;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused by what reloadPage does, when you call $.mobile.changePage you can pass in reloadPage, but this will only reload the cached copy of the current page.

If what you're looking for is a refresh you need to tell jQM not to load via AJAX by using a link with `data-ajax="false"` or rel="external" (for outside of domain links)

Are you trying to learn jQM by editing the jQM documentation page? The link in question is:
`<a href="docs/about/intro.html" class="ui-link-inherit">Intro to jQuery Mobile</a>` if you just added data-ajax="false" to that it will load intro.html in a new page (full refresh).

If you really did want to pass reloadPage: true in this instance, you'd need to change the href to a #, then bind a handler that calls $.mobile.changePage with reloadPage: true passed in as an option, or just use the onClick attribute (not pretty)

Comment: I'm only using the docs page as an example. In the actual application the page isnt cached because the url has a query string which according to the chrome debugger is not cached when switching between tabs (unlike the docs page which I see is cached when switching 'tabs'). Can you elaborate or provide a code snippet for `change the href to a # then bind a handler` ?